# php $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] does not reflect Apache httpd-vhosts.com server root

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

Environment is Windows/Wampserver/Apache/PHP 8.1, Netbeans as the IDE.

The  httpd-vhosts.com file for the virtual host has the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.test.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/dev.test.com"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/dev.test.com/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When running the php code in an test.php file with:

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

I get:

```
C:/wamp64/www
```

Why does it not return:

```
C:/wamp64/www/test
```

What changes can be made to have $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] return the same DocumentRoot in the VirtualHost?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: other virtual host configuration I used also, references appearing in some of the comments below (I had unintentially used "dev.test.com" as the virtual host example)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/test"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/test/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What is the location of the `test.php` file? How exactly are you _"running the php code"_? Are you opening it in a browser? If so, are you opening `http://dev.test.com/test.php`?

Comment: Run in a browser:  http://localhost/test/test.php  AND file location is: C:\wamp64\www\test\test.php

Comment: The host in your request does not match the `ServerName` in your [name-based Virtual Host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) so it's probably using the default vhost which has a `DocumentRoot` of `c:\wamp64\www`. Since this question apparently has absolutely nothing to do with that `<VirtualHost>` directive, it's not clear why you thought you'd get anything other than the default

Comment: FYI relying on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is potentially dangerous. It's definitely better to keep your code portable and use `__DIR__`. See [Magic constants](https://www.php.net/manual/language.constants.magic.php)

Comment: @Phil - so the php command has nothing to do with virtual hosts declarations?  Thought it did, so now I know...

Comment: Sorry, what _"php command"_? You said you were running it via Apache and opening it in the browser 

Comment: The php command in the code referred to as $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']...  Sorry, thought it was obvious.

Comment: Ok, so if you put your `test.php` file in `c:\wamp64\www\dev.test.com` and your DNS or `hosts` file has an entry for `dev.test.com` pointing to `127.0.0.1` and you open `http://dev.test.com/test.php` in your browser, then it will show the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as `c:\wamp64\www\dev.test.com`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Phil in the comments!

using http://test/test.php in the browser - NOT http://localhost/test/test.php returned the expected $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] value in php.   (result:  C:/wamp64/www/test)

Same with using http://dev.test.com/test.php - NOT http://localhost/dev.test.com/test.php   (result:  C:/wamp64/www/dev.test.com)

The mistake came from configuring the run environment on my Netbeans.  I had included the "localhost" name in the "run configuration", project URL field when I should have left it out!

Comment: You didn't mention a `test` server name anywhere in your question, only `dev.test.com`